# Split string into two different columns based on keyword in pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset consists column 'useful_crit' in the form of string as datatype "object".

```
Pat_ID   Useful_crit
  1      **inclusive range**:age 35 to 75 - type 2 diabetes **exclusive range**: type 1 diabetes
  2      **inclusive range**:patients aged 21 and above **exclusive range**:patients who are mentally `
```

String in each column consist two common words as inclusive range and exclusive range. Now, I want to create two columns as 'inclusive range' and 'exclusive range' from same string. So output would be something like,

```
Pat_ID   inclusive range                         exclusive range
 1       age 35 to 75 - type 2 diabetes     type 1 diabetes    
 2       patients aged 21 and above         patients who are mentally
```

How to do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [2519]: (df.Useful_crit.str.split('(\**inclusive\**:|\**exclusive\**:)')
              .apply(pd.Series)[[2,4]])
Out[2519]:
                                 2                          4
0  age 35 to 75 - type 2 diabetes             type 1 diabetes
1      patients aged 21 and above   patients who are mentally

In [2520]: df.join(df.Useful_crit.str.split('(\**inclusive\**:|\**exclusive\**:)')
                     .apply(pd.Series)[[2,4]]
                     .rename(columns={2: 'inclusive', 4: 'exclusive'}))
Out[2520]:
   Pat_ID                                        Useful_crit  \
0       1  **inclusive**:age 35 to 75 - type 2 diabetes *...
1       2  **inclusive**:patients aged 21 and above **exc...

                         inclusive                  exclusive
0  age 35 to 75 - type 2 diabetes             type 1 diabetes
1      patients aged 21 and above   patients who are mentally
```

Comment: In this line of code (df.Useful_crit.str.split('(\**inclusive\**:|\**exclusive\**:)')
              .apply(pd.Series)[[2,4]])......what does  .apply(pd.Series)[[2,4]] will do?